# Cannot access liquid object properties (Jekyll)

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I am new to Jekyll and am creating a documentation website for one of my projects. I am trying to create a sidebar that displays the current page in the documentation. To store the structure of the documentation, I created the a file in the `_data` folder called `subsections.yml`. Here is the file:

```
- title: Quickstart # Section
  data:
    - Get started # Subsections
    - The basics
- title: API documentation # Another section with subsections
  data:
    - Introduction
```

Here is an excerpt from the html template file that will be used for pages in the documentation. (liquid template engine):

```
{% assign subsecs = site.data.subsections | where: 'title', page.section %}
```

The code above creates a variable called `subsecs` which is created by reading `subsections.yml` and filtering out the data on the section the documentation page is about. So if the page's section was `Quickstart`, the `subsecs` variable would contain all the data from the `Quickstart` section from `subsecitons.yml`. I tested this out with `{{ subsecs }}` and it worked by outputting:

```
{"title"=>"Quickstart", "data"=>["Get started", "The basics"]}
```

However, when I try to access a certain property from this object like title:

```
{{ subsecs.title }}
```

nothing is returned. Why is this happening, and how can I access property methods in liquid? The syntax looks correct, bu when I try it, an empty string is rendered.

I tried looking at the liquid documentation, but found nothing other than `method.property`, which doesn't work for some reason. I also looked at similar SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` filter is returning an array.

```
{% assign subsecs = site.data.subsections | where: 'title', page.section %}
{{ subsecs | inspect }}
```

`inspect` filter prints => `[{"title"=>"Quickstart", "data"=>["Get started", "The basics"]}]` brackets denotes an array.

You can do :

```
{% assign subsecs = site.data.subsections | where: 'title', page.section | first %}
{{ subsecs | inspect }}
```

The `first` filter extracts the first element of your array.

`inspect` filter now prints => `{"title"=>"Quickstart", "data"=>["Get started", "The basics"]}`

You can now access your object's properties like `subsecs.title`.